# show hide html element and update button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure if this question has been asked before but I am pretty new to Javascript and I was trying this example:

I am trying to change text of button on show/hide of the fieldSet but button setting button text doesnt work properly.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('.indoor').slideDown();
  $('.outdoor').slideDown();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".togOutBtn").click(function(){
        $(".outdoor").toggle(1000);
    });
    $(".togIndorBtn").click(function(){
        $(".indoor").toggle(1000);
    });
});

function btnToggle(elem, text) {
  if (elem.value == "") {
    elem.value = "Hide " + text;
  }

  if (elem.value == "Hide") {
    elem.value = "Show " + text;
    document.getElementById("togOutBtn").innerHTML = elem.value;
  } else {
    elem.value = "Hide " + text;
    document.getElementById("togOutBtn").innerHTML = elem.value;
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="return btnToggle(this, 'Outdoors');" class="togOutBtn" id="togOutBtn">Hide Outdoors</button>
<fieldset class="outdoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Outdoors</legend>
  Temperature:
  <div id="Outtemp"></div>
  Humidity:
  <div id="Outhumid"></div>
  Feels lile:
  <div id="OutheadIndex"></div>
  <button onclick="waterPlant1()">Water the Plant</button>
</fieldset>
<br>
<button onclick="btnToggle(this, 'Indoors');" class="togIndorBtn">Hide Indoors</button>
<fieldset class="indoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Drawing Room</legend>
  Temperature: 23* C
  <br>Humidity: 12%
  <br>Feels lile:18* C
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Also the first field set of *Outdoors* jitters while show hide  compared to the lower one of *indoor*  goes very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get much closer to what you are looking to accomplish! Please let me know if you have any questions.

The advantage with this method is that you bind the two elements by setting the `id` of the button to the `data-bind` of the fieldset. You should never need to change the javascript this will simple scale indefinitely.

Edit: Added a validation so that it only attempts to operate on the fieldset IF it finds one. Whats neat is that now you an also bind multiple fieldsets to the single input if you set multiple data-binds to the same value.

```js
$('fieldset[data-bind]').slideDown();

$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
  let $id = this.id,
      $this = this;
      $bind= '[data-bind="' + $id + '"]';
  
  if($bind.length){
    $( $bind).toggle(1000,function(){
      $this.value.indexOf('Hide') > -1 ?
         $this.value = $this.value.replace('Hide','Show') :
         $this.value = $this.value.replace('Show','Hide');
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="outdoorBtn" value="Hide Outdoors">
<fieldset data-bind="outdoorBtn" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Outdoors</legend>
  Temperature:
  <div id="Outtemp"></div>
  Humidity:
  <div id="Outhumid"></div>
  Feels lile:
  <div id="OutheadIndex"></div>
  <button onclick="waterPlant1()">Water the Plant</button>
</fieldset>
<br>
<input type="button" id="indoorBtn" value="Hide Indoors">
<fieldset data-bind="indoorBtn" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Drawing Room</legend>
  Temperature: 23* C
  <br>Humidity: 12%
  <br>Feels lile:18* C
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your if statement inside btnToggle:

```
if (elem.value == "Hide") {
```

Here you are saying "if the button value is "Hide". It's never going to be Hide. It's going to be "Hide Outdoors".

You fix that by going like this:

```
if (elem.value == "Hide " +text) {
```

You then get the statement "if value = 'Hide Outdoors'" instead of "if value= 'Hide'"

working function:

```
function btnToggle(elem, text) {
  if (elem.value == "") {
    elem.value = "Hide " + text;
  }
  alert(elem.value);
  if (elem.value == "Hide " +text) {
    elem.value = "Show " + text;
    document.getElementById("togOutBtn").innerHTML = elem.value;
  } else {
    elem.value = "Hide " + text;
    document.getElementById("togOutBtn").innerHTML = elem.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using callback of the toggle function and the visibility of the fieldset, no need to have a `onclick` attribute at the level of the button:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('.indoor').slideDown();
  $('.outdoor').slideDown();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".togOutBtn").click(function(){
        $(".outdoor").toggle(1000, function(){
           showHideFunc('togOutBtn', 'Out');
        });
    });

    $(".togIndorBtn").click(function(){
        $(".indoor").toggle(1000, function(){
           showHideFunc('togIndorBtn', 'In');
  });
 });
});

function showHideFunc(elementClass, inOut)
{
  $("." + elementClass).text(function(){ 
                return ($(this).next('fieldset').is(':visible') ) 
                ? 'Hide ' + inOut + 'doors' : 'Show ' + inOut + 'doors' 
   });
}
```

```css
#container1
{
  margin-bottom:10px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
<button  class="togOutBtn" id="togOutBtn">Hide Outdoors</button>
<fieldset class="outdoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Outdoors</legend>
  Temperature:
  <div id="Outtemp"></div>
  Humidity:
  <div id="Outhumid"></div>
  Feels lile:
  <div id="OutheadIndex"></div>
  <button onclick="waterPlant1()">Water the Plant</button>
</fieldset>
  </div>
  
<div id="container2">
<button class="togIndorBtn">Hide Indoors</button>
<fieldset class="indoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Drawing Room</legend>
  Temperature: 23* C
  <br>Humidity: 12%
  <br>Feels lile:18* C
  <br>
</fieldset>
  
   </div>
```

Comment: can you name the anonymous functions of jQuery that show hide the fields , thats what is very confusing for me in jquery

Comment: check the edit, I have wrapped the callback into a simple function call where you pass the class name and the In/Out string

Comment: thanks , the slide down of the *outdoor* fieldset is not smooth at all, which looks so ugly.

Comment: that's because of the poor html markup, each `fieldset` shall have its own container that preserves proper dimension relative to the other container so that when it hides the other container will not stick to it

Comment: How should I handle that ?

Comment: check the edit, I have wrapped the fieldsets with divs and some css

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with Regex

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $('.indoor').slideDown();
  $('.outdoor').slideDown();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 var btnOutState = 0;
 var btnInState = 0;
    $(".togOutBtn").click(function(){
        $(".outdoor").toggle(1000, function(){btnOutState = !btnOutState; btnChangeValue(".togOutBtn", btnOutState)});
    });
    $(".togIndorBtn").click(function(){
        $(".indoor").toggle(1000, function(){btnInState = !btnInState; btnChangeValue(".togIndorBtn", btnInState)});
    });
});

function btnChangeValue(elem, state) {
var pattern = "";
var replace = "";
 if(state){
  pattern = /Hide/g;
  replace = "Show";
 }else {
  pattern = /Show/g;
  replace = "Hide";
 }
 
 newText = $(elem).html();
 $(elem).html(newText.replace(pattern, replace));
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="togOutBtn" id="togOutBtn">Hide Outdoors</button>
<fieldset class="outdoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Outdoors</legend>
  Temperature:
  <div id="Outtemp"></div>
  Humidity:
  <div id="Outhumid"></div>
  Feels lile:
  <div id="OutheadIndex"></div>
  <button onclick="waterPlant1()">Water the Plant</button>
</fieldset>
<br>
<button class="togIndorBtn">Hide Indoors</button>
<fieldset class="indoor" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Drawing Room</legend>
  Temperature: 23* C
  <br>Humidity: 12%
  <br>Feels lile:18* C
  <br>
</fieldset>
```